# Bash - Printing out rows that match parameters

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file that looks like this

```
3 5 4 0
0 0 0 0 
1 3 0 2
```

What I want is my bash script to only print rows that are not all zeroes. So print out would be

```
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

This is what I have, and it runs with no errors but will not print anything

```
    #!/bin/bash
    awk '{total=0; for(i=1;i<NR;i++)$i+=total
    if (total!=0) {for(i=1;i<NR;i++) printf("%d ", $i)}}total=0'
```

Comment: The winner is `anubhava` with the two fastest solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this egrep:

```
egrep -v "^(\<0\> *)+$" file
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

Using awk:

```
awk '{k=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i>0) {k=1;break}} k' file
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

Comment: The thing is though, I want the bash script to do the work. I want to simply ./script < file and then it to print out what I want

Comment: Provided both grep and awk solutions for you.

Comment: As JayPal poinited out in my post, the `egrep` will give false positive for a line like this  `10 20 30 40`

Comment: No this egrep won't give false result due to use of word boundaries in `\<0\>`, you can try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

With awk you can do:

```
awk '{s=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i!=0)s=1}s' file
```

Or in a bit more readable format:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    s = 0 # flag is initialized to zero
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) # For all fields
        if ($i != 0) # If we find a field that is not zero
            s = 1    # then set the flag to 1
}
s # Prints the current line (default action) if the flag is 
  # not zero (and not an empty string)
```

Comment: @Tree55Topz Added an explanation. Let me know if there is something you don't get

Answer (score 2):

Your script is printing nothing because `total=0` is an assignment whose result is zero which is a false condition. Looks like you're back to confusing NR with NF again too.

Anyway, to do what you now say you want is just:

```
$ grep '[^0 ]' file
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Some short `awk`:

```
awk 'NF!=gsub(/0/,"&")' file
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

Another one, even shorter:

```
awk -F"[0 ]*" 'NF>2' file
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

Just for fun, some extra:

```
awk '{a=$0;gsub(/ /,"")} $0+0 {print a}' file
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

The regex Ed uses:

```
awk '/[^0 ]/' file
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

---

And the winner is `anubhava`

I did a test of the different solution using a large file and time how long it takes. This is the result:

```
2.071s          awk '{k=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i>0) {k=1;break}} k' large.txt >output
4.284s          awk 'NF!=gsub(/0/,"&")' large.txt >output
4.645s          awk '{a=$0;gsub(/ /,"")} $0+0 {print a}'  large.txt  >output
5.103s          awk 'NF!=gsub(/0/,"&")' large.txt >output
6.954s          grep '[^0 ]' large.txt >output
7.368s          awk '/[^0 ]/' large.txt  >output
9.374s          awk '{s=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i!=0)s=1}s' large.txt >output
12.007s         perl -lne '$s=0;map{$s+=$_}$_=~/([0-9]+)/g;print $_ if $s>0;' large.txt >output
25.575s         awk  -F"[0 ]*" 'NF>2' large.txt >output
```

Comment: The first solution will break if the line contains something like `10 20 30 40`. That is, 4 fields and though they don't contain all zeros, but enough to break the condition.

Comment: @jaypal I see that now while testing it. Removed anubhavas `egrep` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since `awk` and other suggestions are already posted, here is way of doing it with `perl`:

```
$ perl -lne '$s=0;map{$s+=$_}$_=~/([0-9]+)/g;print $_ if $s>0;' file
3 5 4 0
1 3 0 2
```

Comment: Hooray for CPAN: `perl -MList::MoreUtils=all -lane 'print unless all {$_==0} @F'`